# How to convert month-year time string to time?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a date string like "Jan-95" to actual date Jan-95 or something similar?

Thank you

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(date_col, format='%b-%y')` should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DataFrame Column'], format=specify your format)
```

format in your case would be:

```
format='%b-%y'
```

Comment: `%b-%y` `b` for month abbreviations, and `y` for year short code